# Method ... in type ... from assembly ... does not have an implementation (.NET Standard mystery)

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, .net-standard

I have an ASP.NET Classic / Web API application that works fine so far, but as soon as it links against *a virtually empty* .NET Standard library (it's straight from the wizard), it fails with a strange error in the Windows event logs *but only when deployed* on Azure App Services.. Locally, it still works fine.

The failure can be seen in the Windows Event Logs as an exception with the error

```
Method 'ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync' in type 'System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAppAttribute' from assembly 'VisBricks.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation. at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at ...
```

Despite the namespace this function is indeed defined by us in the VisBricks.Web assembly, but sure *does* have an implementation.

And it works locally, and it works when deployed when not linking against the almost-empty .NET Standard library.

What's going on?